# Tridion 9.5 Core Service - how to fetch list of Publish purpose

Tags: core-service, sites-9.5

With the reference to this thread: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/4597/1556

I am looking for a similar answer where I need to fetch a list of publishing purposes(BPT) instead of PublicationTargets.

Could someone please suggest me this?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve explain a bit more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Core Service, read the BPT from the Publication and then you can get to TargetTypes and their Purpose:

```
var pub = (PublicationData)client.Read("tcm:0-x-1", null);  
var bpt = (BusinessProcessTypeData)client.Read(pub.BusinessProcessType.IdRef, null);
bpt.TargetTypes.Select(tt => tt.Purpose);
```

Comment: Thanks @Neil, this provides list of purpose using coreservice

Answer (score 1):

A Publication/Repository has a `BusinessProcessType` property which tells you what the selected Business Process Type (BPT) is for that Publication/Repository (if any).

A Business Process Type contains a set of Target Types which each have a distinct Purpose.

So, if you are working with TOM.NET and want to get a list of publishing purposes for a given context Publication, your code could look like this:

`contextPublication.BussinessProcessType?.TargetTypes.Select(tt => tt.Purpose);`

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for suggestion, code is currently using coreservice reference and I am not able to figure out similar code in coreservice,  let me check whether TOM.NET can be fit  in my code,

Comment: The domain model is the same for Core Service, but you will need more code: Read Publication, check its `BusinessProcessType` property (which is a Link containing the BPT ID), read the BPT and then obtain the Target Type purposes (the Target Types are part of the BPT).